# On non-trivial proper normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group of order $n$, $H$ a subgroup of $G$ of order $m$, $k=\dfrac{n}{m}$ and $S_k$ the symmetric group on $k$ symbols.

(a) Show that there is a non-trivial group homomorphism $\phi : G\to S_k$.

(b) Assuming $\dfrac{k!}{2}<n$, show that $G$ has a non-trivial proper normal subgroup.

I have solved (a) by using the action of $G$ by left-multiplication on the cosets of $H$. But I cannot proceed with (b).

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If $G$ doesn't, it's simple, which implies the homomorphism from $a$ either is trivial or injective. What does that tell you about the order of $G$. (P.S. As an addendum to part A, note that there is a non-trivial group homomorphism from $G\to A_k$. You will need this for part B)

Comment: @Don Thousand If we have a homomorphism of $G$ as above into $A_k$, that combined with the given hypothesis would give me a clear contradiction, I can see.

But I am having a bit of trouble seeing how do we get a homomorphism into the alternating group.

Comment: Think about $G\to S_k\to A_k$. Note that if we define $S_k\to A_k$ naturally, then $G\to A_k$ must be non-trivial (think about how to show this).

Comment: I am sorry for asking this, but what is the "natural" map from $S_k$ to $A_k$? Where do we send the odd permutations? Where do we send a transposition?

Comment: $A_k$ is a normal subgroup of $S_k$, no?

Comment: That is right. And the kernel of such a map would be cyclic on 2 elements. But I cannot quite think of a map.

Comment: I'm trying not to give away the answer, but figure out how I can give a hint. Not particularly easy. How about this. Consider the map from $S_k\to\{\pm1\}$. That also should get you your desired result, since it'll show that the map from $G\to S_k$ is also a map from $G\to A_k$.

Comment: I am unable to figure it out. :(

Comment: Think about it this way. $G\to S_k\to S_k/A_k$. $G\to S_k/A_k$ must be trivial unless $G\sim\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. If it is trivial, that implies that $G\to S_k$ is also $G\to A_k$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91720/discussion-between-whysee-and-don-thousand).

Comment: The only homomorphism from $S_k$ to $A_k$ is the trivial one, mapping everything to the identity...